# How to make lldb ignore EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception?

Tags: macos, signals, lldb

I am writing a program on Mac OSX depending on the sigaction/sa_handler mechanism. Run a code snippet from user and get ready to catch signals/exceptions at any time. The program works fine, but the problem is I can't debug it with lldb. lldb seems not being able to ignore any exceptions even I set

```
proc hand -p true -s false SIGSEGV 
proc hand -p true -s false SIGBUS
```

The control flow stops at the instruction that triggers the exception and does not jump to the sa_handler I installed earlier even I tried command `c`. The output was:

```
Process 764 stopped
* thread #2: tid = 0xf140, 0x00000001000b8000, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1000b8000)
```

How do I make lldb ignore the exception/signal and let the sa_handler of the program do its work?

EDIT: sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void handler(int signo, siginfo_t *sigaction, void *context)
{
    printf("in handler.\n");
    signal(signo, SIG_DFL);
}

static void gen_exception()
{
    printf("gen_exception in.\n");
    *(int *)0 = 0;
    printf("gen_exception out.\n");
}

void *gen_exception_thread(void *parg)
{
    gen_exception();
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    if(sigaction(/*SIGBUS*/SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        printf("sigaction fails.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    pthread_t id;
    pthread_create(&id, NULL, gen_exception_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(id, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed this in a recent project, so I just built my own LLDB. I patched a line in `tools/debugserver/source/MacOSX/MachTask.mm` from

```
err = ::task_set_exception_ports (task, m_exc_port_info.mask, m_exception_port, EXCEPTION_DEFAULT | MACH_EXCEPTION_CODES, THREAD_STATE_NONE);
```

to

```
err = ::task_set_exception_ports (task, m_exc_port_info.mask & ~EXC_MASK_BAD_ACCESS, m_exception_port, EXCEPTION_DEFAULT | MACH_EXCEPTION_CODES, THREAD_STATE_NONE);
```

which causes the debugserver to be unable to catch `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exceptions. Now, my custom LLDB works just fine: it still catches `SIGSEGV` and `SIGBUS` but no longer enters a silly infinite loop when faced with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Setting `process handle` options on the previously-fatal signals works fine too, and I can now debug SEGV handlers with impunity.

Apple really ought to make this an option in LLDB...seems like a really easy fix for them.

Comment: What do you mean by "built my own LLDB"? I'm presuming LLDB is still the Xcode debugger (I'm using Xcode 6.4). Is this simply a settings change for LLDB that you are talking about? And if so, where is this file `tools/debugserver/source/MacOSX/MachTask.mm`?

Comment: LLDB is open source, so I [downloaded the source code](http://lldb.llvm.org/source.html), made the necessary patches there, and compiled it.

Answer (score 5):

This is a long-standing bug in the debugger interface in Mac OS X (gdb had the same problem...)  If you have a developer account, please file a bug with http://bugreport.apple.com.  So few people actually use SIGSEGV handlers that the problem never gets any attention from the kernel folks, so more bugs is good...

Comment: Hi Jim: I noticed that you commented on [this LLDB bug report](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22868) that "the straight-forward way to do this requires that the debugger run as root". On OS X I'd be perfectly fine running the debugger as root (I understand the bug report was about iOS where this is not possible). Is there any way that I could patch LLDB to allow it to ignore EXC_BAD_ACCESS if the debugger runs as root?

Comment: * filed https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=46412375
* @jim-ingham could you please elaborate on "The straight-forward way to do this requires that the debugger run as root" ? assuming user is ok running gdb as root, how would that work?

Comment: It's really debugserver that would have to run as root.  If it runs as root, it can forward the EXC_BAD_ACCESS to the host exception port (the one that was socketed into the task's exception port till lldb displaced it).  That will turn it into a SIGSEGV which is what you want.  Note, since lldb doesn't listen for BSD signals, this will mean that any unhandled SIGSEGV's will crash your program.  So in fact this method is probably no better than just ignoring EXC_BAD_ACCESS altogether, which would be easier to implement.

Comment: bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=46412375 got 0 response so I filed https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40669

Comment: @timotheecour since [bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com/) is gone, would you please resubmit the bug report at [https://openradar.appspot.com/myradars/add](https://openradar.appspot.com/myradars/add)?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's exactly the same problem, but perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76105049/523079) (which appears to be new in the Xcode 14.3 toolset, since it didn't work with Xcode 14.2 according to my own tests) indicates the long-standing bug in question may have been fixed?

Answer (score 3):

We can do it easily. Just add this code.

```
#include <mach/task.h>
#include <mach/mach_init.h>
#include <mach/mach_port.h>

int ret = task_set_exception_ports(
                                   mach_task_self(),
                                   EXC_MASK_BAD_ACCESS,
                                   MACH_PORT_NULL,//m_exception_port,
                                   EXCEPTION_DEFAULT,
                                   0);
```

Don't forget to do this

```
proc hand -p true -s false SIGSEGV 
proc hand -p true -s false SIGBUS
```

[image]

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <mach/task.h>
#include <mach/mach_init.h>
#include <mach/mach_port.h>

static void handler(int signo, siginfo_t *sigaction, void *context)
{
    printf("in handler.\n");
    signal(signo, SIG_DFL);
}

static void gen_exception()
{
    printf("gen_exception in.\n");
    *(int *)0 = 0;
    printf("gen_exception out.\n");
}

void *gen_exception_thread(void *parg)
{
    gen_exception();
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    task_set_exception_ports(
                             mach_task_self(),
                             EXC_MASK_BAD_ACCESS,
                             MACH_PORT_NULL,//m_exception_port,
                             EXCEPTION_DEFAULT,
                             0);
    
    
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    if(sigaction(/*SIGBUS*/SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        printf("sigaction fails.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    pthread_t id;
    pthread_create(&id, NULL, gen_exception_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(id, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Refer to (Chinese article): https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/33542591

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me. Works great on x64 and arm64, though not through Rosetta.

Comment: For me, this doesn't work on x86_64 through rosetta.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of example code can make a question like this a lot easier to answer ... I've never used the `sigaction` API before but I threw this together -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void segv_handler (int in)
{
    puts ("in segv_handler()");
}

void sigbus_handler (int in)
{
    puts ("in sigbus_handler()");
}

int main ()
{
    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_mask = 0;
    action.sa_flags = 0;


    action.sa_handler = segv_handler;
    sigaction (SIGSEGV, &action, NULL);
    action.sa_handler = sigbus_handler;
    sigaction (SIGBUS, &action, NULL);

    puts ("about to send SIGSEGV signal from main()");
    kill (getpid(), SIGSEGV);

    puts ("about to send SIGBUS signal from main()");
    kill (getpid(), SIGBUS);

    puts ("exiting main()");

}


% lldb a.out
(lldb) br s -n main
(lldb) r
(lldb) pr h -p true -s false SIGSEGV SIGBUS
(lldb) c
Process 54743 resuming
about to send SIGSEGV signal from main()
Process 54743 stopped and restarted: thread 1 received signal: SIGSEGV
in segv_handler()
about to send SIGBUS signal from main()
Process 54743 stopped and restarted: thread 1 received signal: SIGBUS
in sigbus_handler()
exiting main()
Process 54743 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000) 
(lldb)
```

Everything looks like it's working correctly here.  If I'd added `-n false` to the `process handle` arguments, lldb wouldn't have printed the lines about `Process .. stopped and restarted`.

Note that these signal settings do not persist across process executions.  So if you're starting your debug session over (`r` once you've already started the process once), you'll need to re-set these.  You may want to create a command alias shortcut and put it in your `~/.lldbinit` file so you can set the process handling the way you prefer with a short cmd.

Comment: This is not addressing the original problem: your code is not generating EXC_BAD_ACCESS but rather is generating SIGSEGV.  It is EXC_BAD_ACCESS which puts lldb into an infinite loop.