# Intercepting crashes on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, logging

## Description

I would like to catch all exceptions that are occurring in iOS app and log them to file and eventually send them to back-end server used by the app.

I've been reading about this topic and found usage of signals sent by device and handling them, but I'm not sure if it's gonna break App Store Review guidelines or it may introduce additional issues.

I've added following to `AppDelegate`:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { (exception) in  
    log.error(exception)  
}  

signal(SIGABRT) { s in  
    log.error(Thread.callStackSymbols.prettified())  
    exit(s)  
}  

signal(SIGILL) { s in  
    log.error(Thread.callStackSymbols.prettified())  
    exit(s)  
}  

signal(SIGSEGV) { s in  
    log.error(Thread.callStackSymbols.prettified())  
    exit(s)  
}
```

---

## Questions

- Is this good approach, any other way?
- Will it break App Store Review guidelines because of usage of `exit()`
- Is it better to use `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL)` instead of `exit()`?

---

**Resources**

- https://github.com/zixun/CrashEye/blob/master/CrashEye/Classes/CrashEye.swift
- https://www.plcrashreporter.org/
- https://chaosinmotion.blog/2009/12/02/a-useful-little-chunk-of-iphone-code/

Comment: The Crashlytics does the same work. As far as I know, it is allowed, you can use exit() or abort(). I wouldn't go with the kill(getpid(), SIGKILL)

Comment: If you only want to log the errors then you don't need to call `exit()` or `kill()` at all, as just returning from the signal handler will kill the app with a stacktrace.  If you are using Crashlytics (or some other framework like that) then there are certainly requirements about when you set your signal handler and possibly chaining the handler call to the previously-set handler, etc.

Comment: Definitely go with a third party service like Crashlytics, which btw is now a part of Firebase.

Comment: @SachinVas what is major difference between `kill`, `abort` and `exit`? @trojanfoe I will try without calling `kill` or `exit` and see if app will crash normally, first time I tried without return it actually started filling log file infinitely @pckil Since company is strict about using third party frameworks especially ones that handle data on their server Crashlytics is not really an option. Flexibility is required.

Comment: @NajdanTomić You might need to remove yourself as the signal handler once you've seen a signal...

Comment: @trojanfoe What is best way to do that? Should I do it like this: `signal(SIGNAL_INT, SIG_DFL)`?

Comment: Probably better to save the previous handler and restore that instead.

Comment: @trojanfoe do you have any documentation resource regarding this subject? I'm really having hard time to find it, I'm not even sure what keywords to use. I'm stuck with reading header files and their comments but can't figure out how to return previous handler after finishing working on my stuff. Instead application keeps logging things even after I force close it after I removed `exit()` calls. I'm really grateful for your help.

Comment: [This article](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html) is a good start and there approach is to restore the signal handler with `SIG_DFL` but they are not using any other crash monitor s/w, which you may want to do...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

former Crashlytics iOS SDK maintainer here.

The code you've written above does have a number of technical issues.

The first is there are actually very few functions that are defined as safe to invoke inside a signal handler. `man sigaction` lists them. The code you've written is not signal-safe and will deadlock from time to time. It all will depend on what the crashed thread is doing at the time.

The second is you are attempting to just exit the program after your handler. You have to keep in mind that signals/exception handlers are *process-wide* resources, and you might not be the only one using them. You have to save pre-existing handlers and then restore them after handling. Otherwise, you can negatively affect other systems the app might be using. As you've currently written this, even Apple's own crash reporter will not be invoked. But, perhaps you want this behavior.

Third, you aren't capturing all threads stacks. This is critical information for a crash report, but adds a lot of complexity.

Fourth, signals actually aren't the lowest level error system. Not to be confused with run time exceptions (ie `NSException`) **mach exceptions** are the underlying mechanism used to implement signals on iOS. They are a much more robust system, but are also far more complex. Signals have a bunch of pitfalls and limitations that mach exceptions get around.

These are just the issues that come to me off the top of my head. Crash reporting is tricky business. But, I don't want you to think it's magic, of course it's not. You **can** build a system that works.

One thing I do want to point out, is that crash reporters give you no feedback on failure. So, you might build something that works 25% of the time, and because you are only seeing valid reports, you think "hey, this works great!". Crashlytics had to put in effort over many years to identify the causes of failure and try to mitigate them. If this is all interesting to you, you can check out a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EsCWWXv7jg) I did about the Crashlytics system.

**Update:**

So, what would happen if you ship this code? Well, sometimes you'll get useful reports. Sometimes, your crash handling code will itself crash, which will cause an infinite loop. Sometimes your code will deadlock, and effectively hang your app.

Apple has made `exit` public API (for better or worse), so you are absolutely within the rules to use it.

I would recommend continuing down this road for learning purposes only. If you have a real app that you care about, I think it would be more responsible to integrate an existing open-source reporting system and point it to a backend server that you control. No 3rd parties, but also no need to worry about doing more harm than good.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out technical issues and explaining what is going on in the background. I've noticed that this is not safe at all and even if application is actually in crash state already with my code it's even more unstable and unpredictable. Just seeing that log file is getting populated after app is force closed is really scary. This is definitely something that requires a lot of research and good understanding. I'll check your talk as well.

Comment: You are welcome! Please ask me any questions you have.  And, no need to be scared! You're just seeing normal stuff with crash reporting. Things work, but they just cannot be relied on to work in all cases. Honestly, async-safety is not that important relative to other reliability issues. But, they're an important aspect overall.

Comment: Thanks for encouragement. Great talk as well, it was pretty understandable for someone like me who doesn't know much about this topic. I wanted to log at least something to help debugging crashes without exposing data to the third parties. Since crash reporting systems are separate business I expected challenges like this. I could just handle `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` but I wanted to log errors not just raised exceptions. 

To summarize: this is valid approach but badly executed, code like this should pass Apple Review process. Am I correct?
Is it okay if I contact you via Twitter dm?

Comment: You can absolutely can contact me. But, I may want to post some of my thoughts here, just in case others are following along. And as for `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`, I wouldn't even waste my time with that. The vast majority of crashes are not Obj-C exceptions. So, to do all the work to capture, package and relay the reports, and then handle them server-side just doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: @Mattie do you know if Crashlytics can capture exit(0) as crashes?

Comment: @iosaddicted It *could* vis something like the ‘atexit’ function. But, I never added that, and I think its unlikely anyone has since.

Comment: @Mattie Thank you so much for tour answer! After reading your post I am a little scared about creating my own OOM reporter since I don’t want to break crashlytics. I use crashlytics and Fabric currently, but they dont seem to provide hookd for out of memory related terminations, and I would like to log them with my own logger as well. Do you know of an easy way to achieve this? Hope you don’t mind me asking

Comment: @iOSAddicted I would write to them and ask. I'm not familiar enough with the implementation to say for sure.

Comment: @Mattie How to debug crash handler code line by line? What lldb command should be done? Thanks.

Comment: @James I do not know of a reliable way to use a debugger for a crash handler, and it may well not be possible, as handler mechanisms themselves interfere with the debugger. But, if you figure it out, post it here!

Comment: @Mattie Here is the way I use to debug Firebase.
1. Run the app without lldb.
2. Attach the app with lldb.
3. (lldb) process handle -s false SIGABRT SIGSEGV SIGBUS SIGFPE SIGILL SIGTRAP
4. Make a crash like "abort()".

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829119/how-to-make-lldb-ignore-exc-bad-access-exception)`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829119/how-to-make-lldb-ignore-exc-bad-access-exception`

Comment: @Mattie would there be an issue if I use this just to get a count of the crashes? I don't want to exit or do anything, I just want to find whether the app had crashed previously by storing the crash count in user defaults.

Answer (score 6):

## Conclusion

It is possible to create custom crash reporter but it is definitely not recommended because there is a lot going on in background that could be easily forgotten and can introduce a lot of undefined behaviors. Even usage of third party frameworks can be troublesome but it is generally better way to go.

Thanks to everyone for providing information regarding this topic.

### Answers to questions

#### Is this good approach, any other way?

Approach I mentioned in original question will have influence on Apple's own crash reporter and it introduces undefined behavior because of bad handling of signals. UNIX signals are not covering every error and API handling work with async signal safe functions. Mach exception handling which is used by Apple's crash reporter is better option but it is more complex.

#### Will usage of `exit()` break Apple App Store review?

No. Usage of `exit()` is more related to the normal operation of app. If app is crashing anyway, calling `exit()` isn't problem.

#### Is it better to use kill(getpid(), SIGKILL) instead of exit()?

Quote from Eskimo:

> You must not call exit.  There’s two problems with doing that:
>
> exit is not async signal safe.  In fact, exit can run arbitrary code
>   via handlers registered with atexit.  If you want to exit the process,
>   call _exit.
>
> Exiting the process is a bad idea anyway, because it will either
>   prevent the Apple crash reporter from running or cause it to log
>   incorrect state (the state of your signal handler rather than the
>   state of the crashed thread).
>
> A better solution is to unregister your signal handler (set it to
>   SIG_DFL) and then return

---

## Additional details (full context)

Since I cross posted this questions to [Apple's official support forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/349503) and got really long and descriptive answer from well known Eskimo I would like to share it with anyone who decides to go same path as I did and starts researching this approach.

**Quote from Eskimo**

> Before we start I’d like you to take look at my shiny new [Implementing
>   Your Own Crash Reporter post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113742).  I’ve been meaning to write this up for
>   a while, and your question has give me a good excuse to allocate the
>   time.
>
> You wrote:
>
> I've got a requirement to catch all exceptions that are occuring in
>   iOS app and log them to file and eventually send them to back-end
>   server used by the app.
>
> I strongly recommend against doing this.  My [Implementing Your Own
>   Crash Reporter](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113742) post explains why this is so hard.  It also has some
>   suggestions for how to avoid problems, but ultimately there’s no way
>   to implement a third-party crash reporter that’s reliable, binary
>   compatible, and sufficient to debug complex problems
>
> With that out of the way, let’s look at your specific questions:
>
> Is this good approach at all?
>
> No.  The issue is that your minimalist crash reporter will disrupt the
>   behaviour of the Apple crash reporter.  The above-mentioned post
>   discusses this problem in gory detail.
>
> Will it break App Store Review guidelines because of usage of exit()?
>
> No.  iOS’s prohibition against calling exit is all about the normal
>   operation of your app.  If your app is crashing anyway, calling exit
>   isn’t a problem.
>
> However, calling exit will exacerbate the problem I covered in the
>   previous point.
>
> Is it better to use kill(getpid(), SIGKILL) instead?
>
> That won’t improve things substantially.
>
> callStackSymbols are not symbolicated, is there a way to symbolicate
>   callStackSymbols?
>
> No.  On-device symbolication is extremely tricky and should be
>   avoided.  Again, I go into this in detail in the post referenced
>   above.
>
> Share and Enjoy

---

**Since links can break I will also quote post.**

> ## Implementing Your Own Crash Reporter
>
> I often get questions about third-party crash reporting.  These
>   usually show up in one of two contexts:
>
> - Folks are trying to implement their own crash reporter.
> - Folks have implemented their own crash reporter and are trying to debug a problem based on the report it generated.
>
> This is a complex issue and this post is my attempt to untangle some
>   of that complexity.
>
> If you have a follow-up question about anything I've raised here,
>   please start a new thread in .
>
> **IMPORTANT** All of the following is my own direct experience.  None of it should be considered official DTS policy.  If you have questions
>   that need an official answer (perhaps you’re trying to convince your
>   boss that implementing your own crash reporter is a very bad idea :-),
>   you should open a [DTS tech support
>   incident](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) and we can
>   discuss things there.
>
> Share and Enjoy  —  Quinn “The Eskimo!”  Apple Developer Relations,
>   Developer Technical Support, Core OS/Hardware  `let myEmail = "eskimo"
>   + "1" + "@apple.com"`
>
> ---
>
> ### Scope
>
> First, I can only speak to the technical side of this issue.  There
>   are other aspects that are beyond my remit:
>
> - I don’t work for App Review, and only they can give definitive answers about what will or won’t be allowed on the store.
> - Doing your own crash reporter has significant privacy implications.
>
> **IMPORTANT** If you implement your own crash reporter, discuss the privacy impact with a lawyer.
>
> This post assumes that you are implementing your own crash reporter. 
>   A lot of folks use a crash reporter from another third party.  From my
>   perspective these are the same thing.  If you use a custom crash
>   reporter, you are responsible for its behaviour, both good and bad,
>   regardless of where the actual code came from.
>
> **Note** If you use a crash reporter from another third party, run the tests outlined in *Preserve the Apple Crash Report* to verify that
>   it’s working well.
>
> ### General Advice
>
> **I strongly advise against implementing your own crash reporter.**  It’s very easy to implement a basic crash reporter that works well
>   enough to debug simple problems.  It’s impossible to create a good
>   crash reporter, one that’s reliable, binary compatible, and sufficient
>   to debug complex problems.
>
> “Impossible?”, I hear you ask, “That’s a very strong word for Quinn to
>   use.  He’s usually a lot more circumspect.”  And yes, that’s true, I
>   usually am more circumspect, but in this case I’m *extremely*
>   confident of this conclusion.
>
> There are two fundamental problems with implementing your own crash
>   reporter:
>
> - On iOS (and the other iOS-based platforms, watchOS and tvOS) your crash reporter must run inside the crashed process.  That means it can
>     never be 100% reliable.  If the process is crashing then, by
>     definition, it’s in an undefined state.  Attempting to do real work in
>     that state is just asking for problems [1](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/349503).
> - To get good results your crash reporter must be intimately tied to system implementation details.  These can change from release to
>     release, which invalidates the assumptions made by your crash
>     reporter.  This isn’t a problem for the Apple crash reporter because
>     it ships with the system.  However, a crash reporter that’s built in
>     to your product is always going to be brittle.
>
>   I’m speaking from hard-won experience here.  I worked for DTS during
>     the PowerPC-to-Intel transition, and saw a lot of folks with custom
>     crash reporters struggle through that process.
>
> Still, this post exists because lots of folks ignore my general
>   advice, so the subsequent sections contain advice about specific
>   technical issues.
>
> **WARNING** Do not interpret any of the following as encouragement to implement your own crash reporter.  I strongly advise against that. 
>   However, if you ignore my advice then you should at least try to
>   minimise the risk, which is what the rest of this document is about.
>
> [1](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/349503) On macOS it’s possible for your crash reporter to run out of
>   process, just like the Apple crash reporter.  However, that presents
>   its own problems: When running out of process you can’t access various
>   bits of critical state for the crashed process without being tightly
>   bound to implementation details that are not considered API.
>
> ### Preserve the Apple Crash Report
>
> You must ensure that your crash reporter doesn’t disrupt the Apple
>   crash reporter.  Some fraction of your crashes will not be caused by
>   your code but by problems in framework code, and a poorly written
>   crash reporter will disrupt the Apple crash reporter and make it
>   harder to diagnose those issues.
>
> Additionally, when dealing with really hard-to-debug problems, you
>   really need the more obscure info that’s shown in the Apple crash
>   report.  If you disrupt that info, you end up making the hard problems
>   harder.
>
> To avoid these issues I recommend that you test your crash reporter’s
>   impact on the Apple crash reporter.  The basic idea is:
>
> 1. Create a program that generates a set of specific crashes.
> 2. Run through each crash.
> 3. Verify that your crash reporter produces sensible results.
> 4. Verify that the Apple crash reporter also produces sensible results.
>
> With regards step 1, your test suite should include:
>
> - An un-handled language exception thrown by your code
> - An un-handled language exception thrown by the OS (accessing an `NSArray` out of bounds is an easy way to get this)
> - A memory access exception
> - An illegal instruction exception
> - A breakpoint exception
>
> Make sure to test all of these cases on both the main thread and a
>   secondary thread.
>
> With regards step 4, check that the resulting Apple crash report
>   includes correct values for:
>
> - The exception info
> - The crashed thread
> - That thread’s state
> - Any application-specific info, and especially the last exception backtrace
>
> ### Signals
>
> Many third-party crash reporters use UNIX signals to catch the crash. 
>   This is a shame because using Mach exception handling, the mechanism
>   used by the Apple crash reporter, is generally a better option. 
>   However, there are two reasons to favour UNIX signals over Mach
>   exception handling:
>
> - On iOS-based platforms your crash reporter must run in-process, and doing in-process Mach exception handling is not feasible.
> - Folks are a lot more familiar with UNIX signals.  Mach exception handling, and Mach messaging in general, is pretty darned obscure.
>
> If you use UNIX signals for your crash reporter, be aware that this
>   API has some gaping pitfalls.  First and foremost, your signal handler
>   can only use *async signal safe* functions [1](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/349503).  You can find a list
>   of these functions in the `sigaction` [man
>   page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/reading_unix_manual_pages)
>   [2](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113742).
>
> **WARNING** This list does not include `malloc`.  This means that a crash reporter’s signal handler cannot use Objective-C or Swift, as
>   there’s no way to constrain how those language runtimes allocate
>   memory.  That means you’re stuck with C or C++, but even there you
>   have to be careful to comply with this constraint.
>
> > The Operative: It’s worse than you know.
>
> Many crash reports use functions like `backtrace` (see its [man
>   page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/reading_unix_manual_pages))
>   to get a backtrace from their signal handler.  There’s two problems
>   with this:
>
> - `backtrace` is not an async signal safe function.
> - `backtrace` uses a naïve algorithm that doesn’t deal well with cross signal handler stack frames [3].
>
> The latter example is particularly worrying, because it hides the
>   identity of the stack frame that triggered the signal.
>
> If you’re going to backtrace out of a signal, you must use the crashed
>   thread’s state (accessible via the handlers `uap`parameter) to start
>   your backtrace.
>
> Apropos that, if your crash reporter wants to log the state of the
>   crashed thread, that’s the place to get it.
>
> Finally, there’s the question of how to exit from your signal handler.
>   **You must not call exit**.  There’s two problems with doing that:
>
> - `exit` is not async signal safe.  In fact, `exit` can run arbitrary code via handlers registered with `atexit`.  If you want to exit the
>     process, call `_exit`.
> - Exiting the process is a bad idea anyway, because it will either prevent the Apple crash reporter from running or cause it to log
>     incorrect state (the state of your signal handler rather than the
>     state of the crashed thread).
>
> A better solution is to unregister your signal handler (set it to
>   `SIG_DFL`) and then return.  This will cause the crashed process to
>   continue execution, crash again, and generate a crash report via the
>   Apple crash reporter.
>
> [1](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/349503) While the common signals caught by a crash reporter are not
>   technically async signals (except `SIGABRT`), you still have to treat
>   them as async signals because they can occur on any thread at any
>   time.
>
> [2](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113742) It’s reasonable to extend this list to other routines that are
>   implemented as thin shims on a system call.  For example, I have no
>   qualms about calling `vm_read` (see below) from a signal handler.
>
> [3] Cross signal handler stack frames are pushed on to the stack by
>   the kernel when it runs a signal handler on a thread.  As there’s no
>   API to learn about the structure of these frames, there’s no way to
>   backtrace across one of these frames in isolation.  I’m happy to go
>   into details but it’s really not relevant to this discussion.  If
>   you’re interested, start a new thread in and we can chat there.
>
> ### Reading Memory
>
> A signal handler must be very careful about the memory it touches,
>   because the contents of that memory might have been corrupted by the
>   crash that triggered the signal.  My general rule here is that the
>   signal handler can safely access:
>
> - Its code
> - Its stack
> - Its arguments
> - Immutable global state
>
> In the last point, I’m using *immutable* to mean *immutable after
>   startup*.  I think it’s reasonable to set up some global state when
>   the process starts, before installing your signal handler, and then
>   rely on it in your signal handler.
>
> Changing any global state after the signal handler is installed is
>   dangerous, and if you need to do that you must be careful to ensure
>   that your signal handler sees a consistent state, even though a crash
>   might occur halfway through your change.
>
> Note that you can’t protect this global state with a mutex because
>   mutexes are not async signal safe (and even if they were you’d
>   deadlock if the mutex was held by the thread that crashed).  You
>   should be able to use atomic operations for this, but atomic
>   operations are notoriously hard to use correctly (if I had a dollar
>   for every time I’ve pointed out to a developer they’re using atomic
>   operations incorrectly, I’d be very badly paid (-: but that’s still a
>   lot of developers!).
>
> If your signal handler reads other memory, it must take care to avoid
>   crashing while doing that read.  There’s no BSD-level API for this
>   [1](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/349503), so I recommend that you use `vm_read`.
>
> [1](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/349503) The traditional UNIX approach for doing this is to install a
>   signal handler to catch any memory exceptions triggered by the read,
>   but now we’re talking signal handling within a signal handler and
>   that’s just silly.
>
> ### Writing Files
>
> If your want to write a crash report from your signal handler, you
>   must use low-level UNIX APIs (`open`, `write`, `close`) because only
>   those low-level APIs are documented to be async signal safe.  You must
>   also set up the path in advance because the standard APIs for
>   determining where to write the file (`NSFileManager`, for example) are
>   not async signal safe.
>
> ### Offline Symbolication
>
> Do not attempt to do symbolication from your signal handler.  Rather,
>   write enough information to your crash report to support offline
>   symbolication.  Specifically:
>
> - The addresses to symbolicate
> - For each Mach-O image in the process:
>
>   - The image path
>   - The image UUID
>   - The image load address
>
> You can get most of the Mach-O image information using the APIs in
>   `<mach-o/dyld.h>` [1](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/349503).  Be aware, however, that these APIs are not
>   async signal safe.  You’ll need to get this information in advance and
>   cache it for your signal handler to record.
>
> This is complicated by the fact that the list of Mach-O images can
>   change as you process loads and unloads code.  This requires you to
>   share mutable state with your signal handler, which is exactly what I
>   recommend against in *Reading Memory*.
>
> **Note** You can learn about images loading and unloading using `_dyld_register_func_for_add_image`
>   and`_dyld_register_func_for_remove_image` respectively.
>
> [1](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/349503) I believe you’ll need to parse the Mach-O load commands to get the
>   image UUID.