# Why is LLDB generating EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION with user compiled library on MacOS?

Tags: c, macos, lldb

I want to debug OpenSSL on MacOS to see how it creates an elliptic curve point. So, I compiled OpenSSL with debug symbols and no optimizations. However, when I run with `lldb`, it doesn't work

```
$ cat ec.c
#include <crypto/ec.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    EC_GROUP *group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp384r1);
    EC_POINT *point = EC_POINT_new(group);
    printf("done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is how I compiled and ran the program:

```
$ gcc ec.c -o ec -I../openssl/include ../openssl/libcrypto.dylib  -ggdb3 -O0
$ DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=../openssl/libcrypto.dylib ./ec
done!
```

Here is what happens when I run lldb and try to break at main:

```
$ lldb ./ec
(lldb) process launch --environment DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=../openssl/libcrypto.dylib ./ec
Process 3948 launched: '/Users/seanthomas/repos/ec/ec' (arm64)
Process 3948 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=1, subcode=0x4a03000)
    frame #0: 0x00000001009651a8 libcrypto.3.dylib`_armv8_sve_probe
libcrypto.3.dylib`:
->  0x1009651a8 <+0>: eor    z0.d, z0.d, z0.d
    0x1009651ac <+4>: ret    

libcrypto.3.dylib`:
    0x1009651b0 <+0>: xar    z0.d, z0.d, z0.d, #0x20
    0x1009651b4 <+4>: ret    
Target 0: (ec) stopped.
(lldb)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try using DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH pointing to the directory containing your newly built libcrypto.dylib.  That variable just tells dyld that if it's looking to load that library, look over here first.  DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES is a much more aggressive way to interpose with a library, and that might be causing this different behavior.

Comment: @JimIngham Thanks for the suggestion. The same thing happened, but it was informative to learn that there is another environment variable that does something similar.

Comment: This was totally hacky, but I ended up putting an infinite while-loop, then attaching to the process with `lldb` and changing the flag to break out of the while-loop.

Comment: @SeanThomas I can't find an OpenSSL bug reported in their tracker.  Anyone else find it?

Comment: @SeanThomas I believe I've found a solution to your issue. You can ask `lldb` to ignore `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` by adding it to `platform.plugin.darwin.ignored-exceptions`. I've left a more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem, where on an M2 mac I had a test that linked indirectly to `libcrypto.dylib` and I couldn't get past the on-startup dynamic instruction probes  when running under `lldb`. My first attempt at getting it to work was to adjust the handling for `SIGILL`, but that didn't work out.

Amazingly, I got lucky with `apropos`:

```
(lldb) apropos EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
No commands found pertaining to 'EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION'. Try 'help' to see a complete list of debugger commands.

The following settings variables may relate to 'EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION':
  platform.plugin.darwin.ignored-exceptions -- List the mach exceptions to ignore, separated by '|' (e.g. 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS|EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION'). lldb will
                                               instead stop on the BSD signal the exception was converted into, if there is one.
```

That (and some furious running of `lldb` help commands) got me to:

```
settings set platform.plugin.darwin.ignored-exceptions EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
```

After running that, then you get the expected `SIGILL`:

```
Process 75441 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGILL
    frame #0: 0x0000000101b53328 libcrypto.3.dylib`_armv8_sve_probe
libcrypto.3.dylib`:
->  0x101b53328 <+0>: eor    z0.d, z0.d, z0.d
    0x101b5332c <+4>: ret

libcrypto.3.dylib`:
    0x101b53330 <+0>: xar    z0.d, z0.d, z0.d, #0x20
    0x101b53334 <+4>: ret
```

And then you can either continue past the `SIGILLS` of which I only got three (and which doesn't seem to work for the `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` situation) or use the regular signal management settings to deal with it as you like. For instance:

```
(lldb) process handle SIGILL -n false -p true -s false
NAME         PASS   STOP   NOTIFY
===========  =====  =====  ======
SIGILL       true   false  false
```

And then you won't even see the `SIGILL` stop. That may or may not be the right thing to do, since you probably do want to know about `SIGILL` in most cases.

Comment: Can you give some information about your environment, e.g. macOS version, LLDB version, whether you're running a non-standard LLDB (perhaps from Homebrew or compiled from source)? I ask because `settings set platform.plugin.darwin.ignored-exceptions EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` returns `error: invalid value path 'platform.plugin.darwin.ignored-exceptions'` for me. Also, `apropos EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` doesn't mention the second part for me either ("The following settings variable may relate to...")

Comment: @swineone - Running Ventura 13.3 on a 2022 m2 MacBook Air, using Xcode 14.3 `lldb`, running `lldb --version` reports as version `lldb-1403.0.17.64`.

Comment: Just noticed I was running Xcode 14.2. Updating now, and will report back if these options show up.

Comment: OK, on Xcode 14.3 (lldb same version as yours) the command is now recognized. Can confirm that this fixes the issue for me as well. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Thanks for that! I put it in the lldb config path (~/.lldbinit) and now debugging's working again.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether this can help you or not. But perhaps, there're bugs in libcrypto.3.dylib on Arm arch.

I met this problem also. It works when I run the program by cmd line in shell. But it meets this problem when I want to debug this program in VSCode using lldb.

How ever, when I delete the libcrypto.3.dylib and libssl.3.dylib, build the openssl using tag OpenSSL_1_1_1m, and rebuild the program. It works!

Comment: Do you have problems with the latest versions of OpenSSL?  Just curious.  Also, you using Homebrew or Macports?

Comment: It's not a bug. See my answer for an explanation of what is actually happening.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of OpenSSL attempt to employ the latest ARMv8 extensions if available to achieve the best possible performance, such as SVE2 (responsible for the `eor z0.d, z0.d, z0.d` instruction) and SVE2-SHA3 (responsible for the `xar z0.d, z0.d, z0.d, #0x20` instruction). I've also found a third check for the RNG extension, with instructions such as `mrs x0, RNDR` and `mrs x0, RNDRRS`. None of these extensions are supported by Apple's current processors (M1 and M2 as of this writing).

I'm not familiar with available mechanisms for checking CPU extensions on AArch64. On Intel, I believe, the CPUID instruction will indicate which extensions are available, and this instruction should be available on all 64-bit Intel-compatible CPUs. If my understanding is correct, checking for features on Intel is quite simple and doesn't cause the kinds of troubles reported in the question.

On the other hand, either such a feature doesn't exist in AArch64, or if it does exist, the OpenSSL developers were unaware of it, or decided for some reason against using it. As such, the method employed to check whether a given extension is available is to execute an instruction from that extension, while trapping the invalid instruction exception and taking note of whether the extension is supported or not.

While executing outside a debugger, this produces no visible effect; if the extension is not supported, it is trapped, handled and execution proceeds normally. However, LLDB apparently traps it regardless, causing the problem described in the question. Even if execution is resumed, it traps again in the same instruction address, so that user code is never reached.

If moving back to an older OpenSSL is an option, it seems the simplest solution.

However, it's possible to use the latest OpenSSL and get to the main user code for debugging, but it takes a little more work. What I discovered is that it's possible to edit the PC register address while the debugger is stopped, moving it to the next instruction (i.e., add 0x4 to the PC), and then resume execution. After passing the three checks that fail on unsupported extensions, the main user code is reached and can be debugged normally.

However, quite frankly, this is an ugly hack. The real fix would be to configure LLDB not to break on `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`. Unfortunately I'm not nearly knowledgeable enough about LLDB to know how to do this. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I'm no LLDB expert either but I got lucky with `apropos EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` and found a way around. I've posted an answer below.

Comment: Unfortunately, on arm, the [feature enumeration registers](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2021-09/AArch64-Registers/ID-AA64ISAR0-EL1--AArch64-Instruction-Set-Attribute-Register-0?lang=en) are only accessible in privileged mode (kernel and up — EL1 and up in Aarch64 terminology). So user code can't portably test CPU features, you need to cooperation of the OS somehow.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thanks, I wasn't aware of this. On the other hand, it appears OpenSSL will [fix](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/20305) this issue on Apple Silicon in a future version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, confirm the issue on Mac M1/M2. Reverted back to the old version of openssl and the problem got fixed. I use openssl lib in MacOs app of mine and on app launch in Debug mode it gets crashing right away.

Comment: Same error for me with openssl 3.1.0. Reverting to 3.0.8 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Confirming: Ventura 13.2.1, MacBookPro M2 Max.

First installed OpenSSL 3.1.0, (from https://www.openssl.org/source/), using terminal.app

1. ./config
2. make
3. sudo make install

which generated a runtime EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when the resulting libs were linked with test C source for a Mosquitto client (again within Xcode). i.e.:

[Xcode 14.2 immediate crash on "run"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNxfX.png)

Then installed openSSL 3.0.8 from the same link/site (without removing 3.1.0) using the same 3 "terminal.app" steps.

No crash on running same test program within Xcode.

Thanks so much for the solution. That would have taken me a long time to find.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade works for me. Here is how I did on my mac. Don't want to build from source. Also not sure if this is the right way. (It fixed my problem anyway)

```bash
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew install openssl@3.0
cd /opt/homebrew/opt
ln -s openssl\@3.0 openssl\@3
```

Answer (score 0):

Analysis in other answers appears to be correct, specifically that OpenSSL's probing using potentially invalid extensions, and LLDB catching SIGILL, seems to be the root cause.

Here's the workaround wrapped as a oneliner that persists:

```
echo -e "set platform.plugin.darwin.ignored-exceptions EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION\nprocess handle SIGILL -n false -p true -s false" >> ~/.lldbinit
```

lldb will execute commands in `~/.lldbinit` on startup meaning you don't need to ignore the exception and set signal dispositions on every run.

I did a quick check to see if the program being debugged could modify settings in the debugger dynamically as it can with LSAN, but no luck so far.  Ideally we'd dynamically change whether `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` threw an exception based on the area of code.

Answer (score 0):

Initially my `vcpkg.json` looked liked this:

```json
{
  "name": "vocal-synth-grpc",
  "version-string": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": [
    "grpc",
    "protobuf",
    "zlib",
    "catch2"
  ]
}
```

I updated to this during some debugging:

```json
{
  "name": "vocal-synth-grpc",
  "version-string": "0.0.1",
+ "builtin-baseline": "3426db05b996481ca31e95fff3734cf23e0f51bc",
  "dependencies": [
+   "openssl",
    "grpc",
    "protobuf",
    "zlib",
    "catch2"
  ]
}
```

And now I don't hit this issue. I'm guessing explicitly adding `openssl` to the list for some reason helps this.